# Nginx file upload pauses / stalls in the middle (uploads only 258kb and stops) - 408 request timeout

Tags: nginx, bitnami

I have install bitnami nginx stack (nginx, php-fpm, mysql) to run multiple drupal 7 and node.js sites, but for now there is only one D7 site installed.

File upload works perfectly in localhost. But as soon as I upload it to Linode vps with bitnami nginx stack, it starts showing uploading issues.

For smaller files (~60kb) upload works fine. But for litter bigger files, upload halts. Few cases:
563KB file - upload halts at 46%
3.5MB file - halts at ~7%

access logs looks like this for POST (gives 408):

```
x.x.x.x - - [07/Sep/2014:20:15:24 +0530] "POST /node/add/profile HTTP/1.1" 408 0 "http://mysite[dot]com/node/add/profile" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36"
```

Tried everything I could in the nginx.conf file, but nothing helps.

```
 user  daemon daemon;
 worker_processes  1;

 error_log  logs/error.log;
 #error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
 #error_log  logs/error.log  info;

 #pid        logs/nginx.pid;


 events {
worker_connections  1024;
} 


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access-mysite.com.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

server {
        server_name mysite.com;
        root /var/www/mysite; ## <-- Your only path reference.

        # Enable compression, this will help if you have for instance advagg‎ module
        # by serving Gzip versions of the files.
        gzip_static on;

    client_body_in_file_only clean;
    client_body_buffer_size 32K;

    client_max_body_size 300M;

    sendfile on;
    send_timeout 5m;
    client_header_timeout 5m;
    client_body_timeout 10;
        fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 2048m;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        # This matters if you use drush prior to 5.x
        # After 5.x backups are stored outside the Drupal install.
        #location = /backup {
        #        deny all;
        #}

        # Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
        location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
                allow 192.168.0.0/16;
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
                return 403;
        }

        # No no for private
        location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
                return 403;
        }

        # Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
        # period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
        # as Subversion or Git to store control files.
        location ~ (^|/)\. {
                return 403;
        }

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }

        location @rewrite {
                # You have 2 options here
                # For D7 and above:
                # Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
                rewrite ^ /index.php;
                # For Drupal 6 and bwlow:
                # Some modules enforce no slash (/) at the end of the URL
                # Else this rewrite block wouldn't be needed (GlobalRedirect)
                #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7777;
        }

        # Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
        # This is for D6
        #location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ {
        # This is for D7 and D8
        location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443 ssl;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}

# client_max_body_size 300M;

}
```

**UPDATE: tested without using Drupal, just a simple PHP script - same issue. Definitely something to do with nginx/php-fpm!**

**UPDATE 2: switched off php-fpm and tested with just a html page with an upload field. Same issue - its definitely nginx or bitnami!**

Comment: what is max_upload value in php.ini file ?

Comment: apc.max_file_size = 1M, upload_max_filesize = 40M

Comment: I know it's been 3 years but have you eventually found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have client_max_body_size outside of the server definition.  What's the results with it inside the server definition?

In addition, @PratapSingh asked another good question - what is the max_upload_filesize limit in php.ini?

Try [this explanation](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/increase-file-upload-size-limit/) for additional help.

Comment: tried with client_max_body_size inside server definition. Still the same issue.